# Zoom Video Sdk with nextjs

Tags: javascript, canvas, video, next.js, zoom-sdk

```
let Stream = client.getMediaStream()
  let VideoClient = client.getMediaStream()
   Stream.startVideo({
  videoElement: document.querySelector('#self-view-video'),
 })
```

```
<video
              id="self-view-canvas"
              width={540}
              height={320}
              style={{ backgroundColor: 'black' }}
            ></video>

            <video
              id="self-view-video"
              width={540}
              height={320}
              style={{ backgroundColor: '#f1b5b5' }}
            ></video>
```

```
client
        .join(topic, token, userName, password)
        .then(() => {
          const stream = client.getMediaStream()
          const participants = client.getAllUser()
          const currentUser = client.getCurrentUserInfo()
          console.log('as', participants)
          console.log('asUser', currentUser)
          console.log('token', stream)
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log(error)
        })

      setClient(client)
```

video is not working

I need to enable the Video, Audio and Share using the zoom video sdk

Error
reason:
"You must pass a  element to start video capture for Chromium browser, Android browser, and Chrome without SharedArrayBuffer support."
type: "INVALID_PARAMETERS"

Comment: Double check the Video SDK web [start video documentation](https://developers.zoom.us/docs/video-sdk/web/video/#start-video). You are missing some logic.

I would also suggest upgrading to the latest version of the [Video SDK](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@zoom/videosdk).